# Reading Unique mails using gmail API

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I am reading mails using Gmail API, where I could successfully download the mails to my system. The idea is to navigate through all the label and download the mails, but that is resulting in duplicate mail downloading, as a single mail can belong to different label.
I tried looking up for label $All to get unique mails but i guess All Mail Label is not supported in latest Gmail API. Is there a way to read unique mails in gmail?

Comment: If you want to download all the mails, why are you filtering them by a label?

Comment: I want to download all unique mails.

Comment: In that case, List Messages should suffice your requirement. Do not filter by any label and you should get list of unique messages

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could share some link  for the same

Comment: Try it using https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it on your GMail ID and you should see all the unique message ID's returned

Comment: thanks! I will check for it

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing the mailbox can be done using Gmail Synchronization guide:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync

Use history.list() method of Gmail API with Label ID filter and check for 'messagesAdded' section for Message IDs. You will not get the message body, only IDs, and subsequently have to call message.get() with received Message IDs to get message body.

If a message has multiple labels, history.list() will give you messages directly received in a particular label, hence you will not get the same message twice if you call history.list() with different label IDs.

You can also avoid duplicate messages by handling them in your application by storing each message ID in a cache store such as memcache or an in-memory hash table to avoid processing duplicate messages.